# C2DM Registration ID vs GCM Registration ID?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I notice that Google has deprecated C2DM and changes it to GCM.
Then, in its [Migration docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html#client), it states:

> After receiving a response from GCM, the registration ID obtained must
> be sent to the application server. When doing this, the application
> should indicate that it is sending a GCM registration ID so that the
> server can distinguish it from existing C2DM registrations.

For anyone have migrated C2DM to GCM, is the registration ID in different format for both services? Because it states

> the application
> should indicate that it is sending a GCM registration ID so that the
> server can distinguish it from existing C2DM registrations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is the same I believe but the registration ID is different for the two services.
There needs to be indication in the application server because there is a different request to Google for GCM and C2DM.